# How to detect recovery in a retrying Flux?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have successfully setup a `Flux` receiving events from a remote system (the protocol is websocket but that's irrelevant for the question) and handling connection glitches gracefully using `retryBackoff` method. The code (simplified) is something like this:

```
Flux flux = myEventFlux
            .retryBackoff( Long.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofSeconds(5) )
            .publish()
            .refCount();

flux.subscribe( System.out::println );
```

Now I'd like to handle connection lost and connection recovery events in order to show some cues in the UI, or at least register some logs. Detecting errors seems easy, just a `doOnError` before `retryBackoff` does the trick. But recovery is another story... I need something like "first successful event after an error", so I've tryed this:

```
flux.next().subscribe( event -> System.out.println("first = " + event) );
```

It works in the first normal connection (no previous error) but not in subsequent reconnections after errors.

Comment: I suggest you should try doOnNext and doOnError instead.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with what you want to achieve is that there is no way to distinguish two legitimate end-of-line subscribers subscribing to the retrying `Flux` vs one subscriber that triggers two attempts, from the perspective of `myEventFlux`.

So you *could* use `doOnSubscribe` (or `doFirst` since 3.2.10.RELEASE), but it would be subject to the limitation above. It would also trigger on the original connection, not just the retries...

Maybe for the UI use case this would still help?